# Removed an Xposed module but still causing conflict

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gps, geolocation, location-services, xposed-framework

I installed [Disable Location Consent](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.disablelocationconsent) and have been having GPS issues where I cannot actually use High Accuracy mode so I removed this module but the problem still remains. Are there remnants of the modules modifications somewhere? How can I find them? I've already tried wiping Dalvik, Data, and Cache.

Comment: Have you check the xposed module forum site on XDA? Did you deactivate the module before you removed the module?

Comment: yes. i also tried reinstalling to deactivate again and still no luck.

Comment: Did you read through - *http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-disable-google-location-consent-t2449926*

Comment: Did you soft reboot after reinstalling module? Then again after activating the module?

Comment: Also this module shouldn't have any bearing on High Accuracy mode, this is only removing the consent notification. Try and think if there were any settings you changed anywhere else, plus did you install any other modules that would affect the GPS?

Comment: Yes I rebooted as much as reasonable per step. Not to my knowledge but I was planning to re-flash /system to see if that helped. What appears to be happening is that while I have the phone set to high accuracy mode, it appears to be using device only or some ineffective GPS mode that only updates every minute to several minutes and is abysmally inaccurate (useless for driving).

Comment: This is starting to sound like your gps.conf file got borked, which is why i was asking if you added anything else. I have used this ( http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1239713 ) as a fix for bad gps.conf before on a couple of my devices. Read thoroughly, then make a backup, then try. If this fixes your problem, i will post as a answer. Let me know.

Comment: Very good link - I believe it is now fixed and will test it later

Comment: let me know and glad you're making some progress :-)

Comment: So from a little testing I can say it is still having the same problem in the same location as before (my car). It does however work when not connected to my cars bluetooth. Unfortunately it just so happens that the pioneer radio I have has a GPS that I didn't bother installing because I didn't want to use it however I am theorizing that the phone is attempting to use the pioneers GPS and doesn't fall back to the phones GPS at all.

Comment: Try the steps one more time. Follow the directions to the letter. Not saying you didn't, but....make sure you set GPS antenna properly, in settings.

Comment: I outlined the problem in an answer. It's unlikely anyone would have guessed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are more useful for the question but unfortunately in my case the problem was something different.

It just so happens that the pioneer radio I have has a GPS that I didn't bother installing because I didn't want to use it however the phone is attempting to use the pioneers GPS and doesn't fall back to the phones GPS at all.

So if I use the GPS anywhere else (wifi or data) when bluetooth is deactivated, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where my SMS wouldn't send to my contacts. That day I had made a few modifications one included a Xposed module, I uninstalled the module and other modifications, but the problem persisted I resorted to restoring an old backup of my phone and the problem went away. I assume as our using a Xposed module your phone is rooted try restoring to a previous backup, it's always good practice to back up your phone before attempting any modifications. If you don't have a backup, then I'd suggest the only option is to restore your phone using Odin (If your using stock ROM) or to Flash a custom ROM

Answer (score 1):

Very often happens something strange: if you activate the effect of a module and then you remove the module, then the effect will still be there. 
It's the same way of acting as Freedom (for example). 
Try installing again the module, deactivating the effect and uninstalling again. 
This should work. Tell me if it works :)

Comment: Did not work. Something still remains in the way of GPS functioning properly.